# Python - Method that calls itself

Tags: python

I am trying to learn Python. I just made a simple rock, paper, scissors game for practice. I am having a small problem.

When each player choose the same item, the game ends in a tie.

[image]

When the player makes a mistake and has to choose again, the variable is empty. Notice that Player 1 says "none".

[image]

This is the method. The problem occurs in the else branch.

```
def play1():
    player1_choice = input("Player 1 - Go: ")
    if (check(player1_choice)):
        return player1_choice
    else:
        print(error_msg)
        play1() # Something is wrong here.
```

What did I do wrong? How can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: In `else` you should make it `return play1()`

Comment: This function can blow your stack if a player is dumb or malicious.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use recursion if you don't have to. Try this:

```
def play1():
    while True:
        player1_choice = input("Player 1 - Go: ")
        if (check(player1_choice)):
            return player1_choice
        else:
            print(error_msg)
```

Comment: Great. That works well. Thank you. The only change is that I added a *break* right after the *return*. I don't know if it is needed but I was worried the loop will go on forever.

Comment: Not only is it not needed, you can't ever get to it -- it's "dead" code.  The **return** takes you entirely out of the function, so that break is non-functional.  It's kind of like handcuffing a suicide victim.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic **while** loop application; you want to loop until you get a reasonable answer (while the known answer is unacceptable), returning that answer to the calling program.

Use a **for** loop when you know *as you enter the loop* how many times you have to repeat it.

Recursion is proper when you have a job in which you can:

1. do something simple;
2. reduce the remaining task to something smaller, closer to a trivial "completed" state;
3. pass that smaller task to the *same* function for further processing.

In this application, getting a wrong answer from the user doesn't put you any closer to a solution (a valid answer) than when you started.  The task isn't any simpler now.  Further processing *is* the same, but you get that just as well with an iteration loop.